# Need an alert on first log in

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a requirement to show an alert box when the user logs in for the first time.

I used the localStorage method as below:

```
var visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');

if (!visited) {
    alert("Please view this is Firefox" + visited);
}
```

However, it seems to be working, but it doesnot work on every login, it works only when the page is visited first time.

Please let me know if there is a way to do it. Please note, I am using javascript to get this functionality done.

Thanks,
Ark

Comment: So it's not when they login for the first time, it's to show whenever they login?

Comment: Remove the item from localstorage again when the user logs out, else it'll stay there until the user clears his/her cache.

Comment: Can you please show where and how this logic is being triggered? Also where and how you are setting local storage?

Comment: If you want the show the alert only in the first login, you need to store this information somehow in your database. Otherwise, both cookies or localStorage won't prevent the message from showing again if your user changes computer...

Comment: Just remove the local storage data on login page load and store it back once logged-in so whenever login page is requested then it will show the message again. Is this what you want? can [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) help you!!!

Comment: yes, I want it when the user logs in and the homepage is presented to him for the first time. However, if I can somehow check if the user logs in or revisiting the page, it will also help

Comment: Guys, thanks for all your help. The sessionStorage seems to have worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sessionStorage` instead `localStorage`.

The other approach is to handle the flag on the backend side and return it with auth response to toggle logic in auth response callback.

Second way is better because it is protected from manual storage cleanup situation.